# spring integration service-activator error

Tags: spring-integration

I try to preprocess a file between a file inbound channel adapter and a FileSplitter. To do this, I wrote a class which performs the job :\

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class ReleaseManagerForFlatFile {

    @ServiceActivator
    public Message<?> processFileCounter(Message<?> message) {
        Get the job Done !
        return message;
    }
}
```

I included it in my spring integration config file :

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
    directory="D:\Donnees\Dev\workspace-luna\FileAggreg\In" id="fileIn"
    auto-startup="true" channel="channelFile" prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="60000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="channelFile" />
<int:service-activator id="releaseManager" input-channel="channelFile" output-channel="channelFileIn" 
    ref="releaseManagerForFlatFile" />
<int:channel id="channelFileIn" />
<int-file:splitter id="splitter" input-channel="channelFileIn" output-channel="channelSplitter" />
```

But, when I launch the chain, I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'releaseManagerControl': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
```

I wrote many service activator before and I never had this issue...
Context : Spring Integration 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with your exact code and had no problems.

> Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.

This implies your `releaseManagerForFlatFile` bean is not a `ReleaseManagerForFlatFile` instance, but some other consumer endpoint in the context.

Perhaps you have a duplicate bean name?

Enabling DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` will help - you can watch the bean definitions being processed and wired together.

Answer (score 0):

I guess yoou need to declard new bean like below

```
<bean id="releaseManagerForFlatFile" class="package.name.ReleaseManagerForFlatFile"></bean>
```

I face the same problem but this works for me. Hope this help.